# Limit involving Riemann sums

Tags: integration, limits, riemann-sum

I want to calculate the following limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2+\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}$$
and I know I can use Riemann sums to transform the limit to a integral, but don't see how to do this in this particular case.

Comment: Multiply and divide by $\pi/n$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**:$$\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \sin  \left( \frac { \pi  }{ n }  \right) \sum _{ k=1 }^{ n } \frac { 1 }{ 2+\cos  \left( \frac { k\pi  }{ n }  \right)  } =\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \frac { \sin  \left( \frac { \pi  }{ n }  \right)  }{ \frac { \pi  }{ n }  } \frac { \pi  }{ n } \sum _{ k=1 }^{ n } \frac { 1 }{ 2+\cos  \left( \frac { k\pi  }{ n }  \right)  } =\\ =\pi \lim _{ n\to \infty  } \frac { 1 }{ n } \sum _{ k=1 }^{ n } \frac { 1 }{ 2+\cos  \left( \frac { k\pi  }{ n }  \right)  } =\pi \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \frac { dx }{ 2+\cos { \pi x }  }  } $$

Comment: Hint? This is the complete solution!(+1)

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\pi   \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \frac { dx }{ 2+\cos { \pi x }  }  }$?

Comment: @TomaszTarka,thank you it was a typo